# Find unknown max/min values of property

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera

I'm working with a camera using the Image Acquisition Toolbox from MATLAB. It allows me to set some parameters like Gain, ExposureTime even if the setted values are not allowed by the camera itself. So my question is, is there any way to obtain the possible max/min values of the parameters?

Comment: There are millions of cameras in the world with different settings. Are you asking for a method in matlab to know the max and min values of each camera?

Comment: I understand that there are many cameras, but if MATLAB is getting the properties of the cameras, it should also be able to know the max/min values for them. It reads the properties from an xml-File that is on the camera and the max/min values are also written there. So maybe there is a possibility to get access to this file using MATLAB?

Comment: You have a way to make Matlab get the properties of all cameras?! I personally, doubt so.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I find a solution. Maybe it will help some other people. MATLAB copy the xml-File from the camera to its cache folder in C:\Users...\AppData\Roamin\MathWorks\R2013b\GenICamXMLCache\***.xml. So now it is only simple xml-reading and searching.